# NSDocument Directory path issue in iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, nsdocumentdirectory

I am working in iPad application, Using Xcode 4.3.2 to develop my app, i have get the pdf file (URL) from web service and that pdf file download in NSDocumentDirectory path then retrieve the pdf file from NSDocument Directory path to show in

```
  NSString *pathlink = (NSDocument Directory Path)
  NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathlink];
  pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
  CFRelease(pdfUrl);

Below this classes for Curl page animation:
LeavesCache.h
LeavesView.h
LeavesViewController.h
Utilities.h
```

Then each page turn in curl animation and run in my ipad simulator and its working fine.
Then i tried to run this app in my iPod device the device version is ios6.1 so, i insert ipa file in itunes connect to run this. when i click to open the pdf file the app was crash, i tried my level best, but i didn't know that, please help me.

Thanks in Advnce

Error:

```
Ipad ReportCrash[7011] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process PublishGenieApplication[7008]
Ipad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.everestindia.apps[0x7e28][7008]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.everestindia.apps[0x7e28]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Ipad backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.everestindia.apps[0x7e28]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Ipad ReportCrash[7011] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
 Ipad ReportCrash[7011] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/genieapplication_2013-02-16-131259_Ipad.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Comment: Try   NSString *directoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 0):

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = (CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:myFilePath];
pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);
CFRelease(pdfURL);
```